# Using a Command Bar inside of the NavView Navigation Pane UWP

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm struggling to create the UI I have in my head and to date have been fairly unsuccessful.

I'm trying to create a Main Page which hosts my NavView and inside of by NavView I wish to have a command bar which will control which NavViewItems are visible. I have created a quick image of what I'm trying to achieve.

In my example I have the home button in the command bar activated which displays

- Nav Item Header
- Navigation Item 1
- etc...

[image]

I want to be able to click documents and have the indicator switch to documents and hide the navigation items corresponding to Home and show the navigation items corresponding to Documents.

Finally, I want the command bar to collapse when the NavView pane is compact but the user should be able to click the Command bar button and expand the command bar to change between Home, Documents etc.

Really looking for any help/advice for the best places to start.

I'm still learning the UWP controls and Xaml.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use a `SplitView` instead of `NavigationView` outside, and then, 
inside the `Pane` of the `Splitview`, use a `NavigationView` with some trick to achieve what you desired.

Key points are:

1. Keep the `NavigationView`'s `PaneDisplayMode` `LeftComact`
2. don't use the `PaneToggleButton` in the `NavigationView` to prevent
   user from changing `PaneDisplayMode` by clicking it, use a custom one instead to open and close pane.
3. Change the `PaneDisplayMode` of the `NavigationView` to `Top` when
   pane opens, and backt to `LeftComact` again when pane closes.

Here is what I have achieved with `NavigationView` inside `Splitview.Pane`:

[image]

You can decorate it and make it more visually satisfying, like adding an `AutoSuggestBox` or `Setting` button, but that's the basic. Btw, don't use the `NavigationView`'s `Setting` button, as I have seen it behaving strangely here.

**XAML:**

```
<SplitView 
    x:Name="Split"
    DisplayMode="CompactInline"
    CompactPaneLength="40">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button
                Click="Button_Click">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="List"/>
            </Button>

            <NavigationView 
                Grid.Row="1"
                x:Name="NavView"
                PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact"
                CompactPaneLength="{x:Bind Split.CompactPaneLength}"
                IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
                IsPaneToggleButtonVisible="False"
                IsSettingsVisible="False"
                SelectionChanged="NavView_SelectionChanged">
                <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                    <NavigationViewItem x:Name="HomeItem" Icon="Home" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    <NavigationViewItem x:Name="DocumentItem" Icon="Document" />
                    <NavigationViewItem x:Name="PeopleItem" Icon="People" />
                </NavigationView.MenuItems>

                <ContentControl>
                    <ListView 
                        x:Name="ItemList"/>
                </ContentControl>

            </NavigationView>

        </Grid>
    </SplitView.Pane>
</SplitView>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public List<string> HomeItemList;
    public List<string> DocumentItemList;
    public List<string> PeopleItemList;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        HomeItemList = new List<string> { "HomeItem1", "HomeItem2", "HomeItem3" };
        DocumentItemList = new List<string> { "DocumentItem1", "DocumentItem2", "DocumentItem3" };
        PeopleItemList = new List<string> { "PeopleItem1", "PeopleItem2", "PeopleItem3" };
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Split.IsPaneOpen = !Split.IsPaneOpen;
        if (Split.IsPaneOpen)
        {
            NavView.PaneDisplayMode = NavigationViewPaneDisplayMode.Top;
        }
        else NavView.PaneDisplayMode = NavigationViewPaneDisplayMode.LeftCompact;
    }

    private void NavView_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            Split.IsPaneOpen = true;
            NavView.PaneDisplayMode = NavigationViewPaneDisplayMode.Top;

            if (sender.SelectedItem == HomeItem)
                ItemList.ItemsSource = HomeItemList;
            else if(sender.SelectedItem == DocumentItem)
                ItemList.ItemsSource = DocumentItemList;
            else if(sender.SelectedItem == PeopleItem)
                ItemList.ItemsSource = PeopleItemList;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this does look awesome and is what I'm after, I think one thing will be making sure the buttons don't jump around too much from compact to expanded... Might have to think a little more about how I want to achieve this. My initial idea was that the command bar in compact would reduce to a single button to keep every thing inline, but I do also like the vertical set out.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to decide if you want to use `NavigationView`. In XAML controls are defined by their behavior (properties and methods that they implement), while the visual appearance is irrelevant and can be altered completely. If `NavigationView` is right for your task then you can alter its style partially or completely - in XAML editor right click on it, then click Edit Template > Edit a Copy. Now you'll get the XAML style definition that defines appearance of `NavigationView`, that's the place to start.

But it might be very well that you can't use `NavigationView` and that starting with `SplitView` might be a better idea as @Muzib said.

Not sure if this is a good idea for learning XAML, but you'll learn one thing - XAML can be customized to the great extent, but doing it may also be a very complex task.

Comment: Thankyou, yes the problem with the NavigationView is the NavigationViewItem has a word behaviour when trying to place a Command Bar inside. I've tried to create my own custom NavigationViewItem but had little success, I do find the SplitView is much easier to understand and customise so maybe this is the way to go. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a few problems from the UX perspective.

1. Not all the navigation items are shown at once and a used must expand the menu to change between the sets of items.
2. The positions of the navigation items changes when the navigation pane is expanded. Currently the way the control works it is though the pane is expanding to show the text of the button. With your suggested approach it would like the items jump down on open.

I wonder if would be easier to have a fixed side pane with the controls laid out like you want and no hamburger button etc. This is not so unusual, the Settings app does it.

If you do go with a fixed width pane, I recommend looking at the XAML that defines the NavigationView control, which can be found inside `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.17763.0\Generic\generic.xaml`
(according to the version of your SDK). Then you can make sure to use the theme resources used by the Windows so that your custom control has a similar look and feel.